# Error: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

I am trying to code a telephone directory for my java project (MATSEC 'O' Levels equivalent to the British GCSE) and while coding (using BlueJ) this error pops up. I am using my teacher's book as a reference and there is nothing related to the error and it doesn't say that I should add anything to it. Here is my java code (Not the main class):

```
import java.io.*;

class Data{
    String read(){  

        String[] name = null;
        String[] surname = null;
        String[] company = null;
        String[] house = null;
        String[] street = null;
        String[] locality = null;
        String[] telno = null;
        String[] mobno = null;
        int entnum;



        BufferedReader txt = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Directory.txt"));

        System.out.println("Name\tSurname\tCompany\tHouse\tStreet\tLocality\tTelephone\tMobile");
            System.out.println("\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        for(entnum = 0;name[entnum]!= null; entnum++){
            name[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            surname[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            company[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            house[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            street[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            locality[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            telno[entnum] = txt.readLine();
            mobno[entnum] = txt.readLine();

            System.out.print(name[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(surname[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(company[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(house[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(street[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(locality[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(telno[entnum]+ "\t");
            System.out.print(mobno[entnum]+ "\t\n");

            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Basically, this simply reads from a text file and displays the entries. I am not yet using GUI.

Comment: If your teacher doesn't understand checked exceptions, he should be replaced **immediately**.

Comment: This is one of the first things you ever learn for file IO.  If your teacher can't do file IO, it's time to upgrade.

Comment: Your teacher doesn't know how to solve this?? Are you serious. Trust me, your programming career is in danger, until you change your teacher.

Comment: Students don't control which teachers teach at their schools

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: Then the school should be replaced immediately. :)

Comment: This tells you why. Please teach your teacher this :)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html

Comment: This is for our GCSEs (equivalent) and we don't have these in our notes.. Frankly we didn't do them yet. Maybe he never used it??? IDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file reading code inside read() method should be wrapped inside try/catch block

(or)

define read() method as  `read() throws FileNotFoundException { .....}`.

`FileNotFoundException` is checked exception, it should be either declared in throws clause (or) Code which may throw this exception should be wrapped in try/catch due to [catch/specify](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Another problem has cropped up. The same error but this time higlighting the ()s:

`name[entnum] = txt.readLine();`

This is in a `for` loop as above. Should I use the throws... in the parenthesis? Thanks @Nambari

Comment: May be you are missing import statements.

Comment: sorry, just finalized the comment as evrytime I press enter it submits it. Should I use `throws ...` in the parenthesis???

Comment: @markscamilleri: see example in my code. You just need to define in method declaration. I would suggest reading the documentation link I have provided in answer.

Answer (score 1):

please put your  Buffered Reader in try catch block :)

Comment: and `catch(FileNotFoundException fe)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use modern IDE, for example, Eclipse. It will help to you to detect many compilation errors.

Comment: I think the difference between BlueJ and Idea (or Eclipse, but I used Idea) is that when I inserted your code in my IDE it said me that your code isn't compiled because there wasn't code for exception :)